# Can I Upgrade My Android Application to Native One after First Release as WebView

Tags: android, web, webview, native

I've decided to release my application as WebView App for Android as for now due to some reasons I want to do it ASAP but I too want to release its second version as a Native Application not the WebView. Does it work out, I mean, if people update from my old app(WebView) to new app(Native one), do they get some issues or the Google Play Store has any restrictions or any other problem can happen?

If not? Then is it good to go WebView first and Native after that?

And what faults does WebView has, I'd be really grateful to hear your answers, thanks !

Comment: Okay. It's been 2 years and by now, I've worked on several Android Apps and no, it doesn't matters whether you first release a native version or webview version, it is totally okay. Just release one that's convenient for you, I hope this comment helps somebody. Also, if anyone needs help understanding more about this can freely add a comment here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you keep the package name (e.g. com.stackoverflow.appname) and signing the same for the webview and native apps you can easily upgrade users from one version to the other using the Google Play store.

More info on signing from [Android Devlopers](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Comment: so I just have to keep the package name unchanged and release future updates with same package name, right?

Comment: Yes, keep package name and signing the same between the versions.